# Undefinde offset:1 when importing laravel excel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

this my code cause the trouble,

```
$cust = Customer::where('name', '=', $data[$i][0]['customer_name'])
    ->pluck('customer_id')[0];
```

this one for get customer id when i do store to sales order

```
$sales = array(
       'customer_id' => Customer::where('name', '=', $data[$i][0]['customer_name'])->pluck('customer_id')[0],
       'logistics_id' => Logistic::where('logistics_name', '=', $data[$i][0]['logistics'])->pluck('logistics_id')[0],
       'subtotal' => $data[$i][0]['subtotal_rp'],
       'shipping_cost' => $data[$i][0]['shipping_cost_rp'],
       'discount_code' => 0,
       'date_of_sales' => $data[$i][0]['date'],
       'grand_total' => $data[$i][0]['grand_total_rp'],
       'tax' => $data[$i][0]['tax_rp'],
       'status' => $data[$i][0]['status'],
       'discount_amount' => $data[$i][0]['discount_amount_rp']
);
$store_so = SalesOrder::create($sales);
```

but, when i do `dd()`, i get the right data

Comment: Don't post images of code please. Post the code in a code block. Is this inside a loop? try `dump()` instead of `dd()` I think the problem comes when $i = 1

Comment: @GertB. i'm so sorry, i'm newbie in stackoverflow. yes, this insede a loop

Comment: @GertB. I use `for($i = 0; $i < total_data; $i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to check if the `$data` variable returns the data as you expect.

```
dd($data);
```

Next, you need to check that the `$data` array has the number of elements according to `$total_data`.

```
dd(count($data) == $total_data));
```

So basically, you just need to give condition or `try-catch` (recommended) :

```
if (isset($data[$i][0])) {
    $customer = Customer::where('name', $data[$i][0]['customer_name'])->first();
    $logistic = Logistic::where('logistics_name', $data[$i][0]['logistics'])->first();

    if(!$customer){
        dd('No customer found!');
    }

    if(!$logistic){
        dd('No logistic found!');
    }

    $sales = [
        'customer_id'     => $customer->customer_id,
        'logistics_id'    => $logistic->logistics_id,
        'subtotal'        => $data[$i][0]['subtotal_rp'],
        'shipping_cost'   => $data[$i][0]['shipping_cost_rp'],
        'discount_code'   => 0,
        'date_of_sales'   => $data[$i][0]['date'],
        'grand_total'     => $data[$i][0]['grand_total_rp'],
        'tax'             => $data[$i][0]['tax_rp'],
        'status'          => $data[$i][0]['status'],
        'discount_amount' => $data[$i][0]['discount_amount_rp'],
    ];
    $store_so = SalesOrder::create($sales);
}
else{
    dd('No $data[$i][0] found!');
}
```

PS : I recommend using the `first()` method instead of `pluck('customer_id')[0]`.

Comment: it worked, thanks. But, if I have 2 data, it only stores 1 data. does it have to do storeing inside foreach?

Comment: No foreach here. Can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to get a `customer_id` from a `customer_name`.
Try to make everything simple:

```
$sales = array(
       'customer_id' => Customer::where('name', $data[$i][0]['customer_name'])->first()->id,
       ...
);
```

Comment: I was try it, but, this one give me `Bad Method Call`

Comment: Sorry, I see you save a field named `customer_id` , not `id` . It should be:
`'customer_id' => Customer::where('name', $data[$i][0]['customer_name'])->first()->customer_id,`